# NGINX Proxy Pass to NodeJS App: Returning 502 error

Tags: nginx, proxy, configuration, 502

I'm trying to setup NGINX as the frontend of my NodeJS app, which is live on `127.0.0.1:3000`, but i can't resolve this 502 error. NGINX is locally reachable at `http://55.55.55.5/` or `http://dev.example`

**dev.example (file in: /etc/nginx/sites-available and symlinked to sites-enabled)**

```
upstream up_dev.example {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name dev.example example;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev.example.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://up_dev.example/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

**error.log**

> 2014/09/17 19:38:26 [error] 1679#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 55.55.55.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:$

Comment: Please avoid using [other poeple's IP addresses](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) in examples - especially when they belong to the US military!

Answer (score 11):

It could also be SELinux that's preventing the connection being made as `httpd_can_network_connect` is off by default.

`getsebool httpd_can_network_connect`

Check if this is turned on. If not, turn it on by running

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`

The `-P` means persistent changes so the new boolean will still be in effect even after a reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Connection refused means that no software is listening to port 3000 on your server. You should check that Node.JS is running properly and that it is listening to port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

```
- proxy_pass http://up_dev.example/
+ proxy_pass http://up_dev.example
```

try it

Comment: Not even close.