# Nodejs Nginx error: (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, node.js, centos7

I'm trying to run multiple Nodejs applications on Nginx server running on CentOS 7. I noticed that when I run a Nodejs app on some ports I get an 502 Bad Gateway error in the browser so I checked the error logs:

```
[notice] 12806#0: signal process started
[crit] 12807#0: *13 connect() to 127.0.0.1:7777 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: **.**.99.58, server: myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:7777/", host: "myapp.com"
[crit] 12807#0: *13 connect() to [::1]:7777 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: **.**.99.58, server: myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:7777/", host: "myapp.com"
```

when I change the app to listen to 8008 for example everything is working fine. I checked permissions and if the process is running as root and everything seems ok. I played with the timeouts as well but no result. Can anyone help?

Comment: Check `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Answer (score 24):

By default SELinux only allows the web server to make outbound connections to a limited set of ports.

```
# semanage port --list
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
```

To fix the problem, you simply need to add your own desired port number to the list.

```
# semanage port --add --type http_port_t --proto tcp 7777
```

Then you will see the port number added into the list, and your connections should then work.

```
# semanage port --list
http_port_t                    tcp      7777, 80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael! I had wasted entire days looking for this specific answer.

Comment: on CentOS 7, `yum install policycoreutils-python` to get semanage

Comment: Hi Michael, when I ran the command `semanage port --add --type http_port_t --proto tcp 7001`. I got `ValueError: Port tcp/7001 already defined`

Comment: And when I ran command `semanage port --list`, I see `afs3_callback_port_t tcp 7001` and `afs3_callback_port_t udp 7001`

Comment: @Isaac Use a different port. If you can't change the port because someone else runs the service, see [here](https://serverfault.com/a/699885/126632) but be aware that this will reduce your security.

Answer (score 0):

I responded to this scenario in the link below.
I was successful

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77552458/6727650

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).