# Weird interaction with systemctl with Haproxy on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, haproxy, systemctl

**Running haproxy through systemctl is different than running it manually**.

- on manual start, everything works.
- starting through systemctl, haproxy is not able to find the service it proxies, and answers with a 503.

Here's the output when starting through systemctl:

```
> sudo systemctl status  -l haproxy.service
haproxy.service - HAProxy Load Balancer
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service; enabled)
                Active: active (running) since Wed 2014-12-24 08:08:49 EST; 4min 59s ago
                Main PID: 20307 (haproxy)
                CGroup: /system.slice/haproxy.service
                └─20307 /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid

                Dec 24 08:08:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting HAProxy Load Balancer...
                Dec 24 08:08:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started HAProxy Load Balancer.
```

Like this, haproxy just says 503 for my backend.

If I now stop the haproxy service, and instead run it manually on the command line, like so:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid
```

it proxies fine to my server.

I've installed haproxy through yum, and I'm using an exceedingly simple configuration:

```
# defaults above

frontend  main *:80
    default_backend app

backend app
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server web1 127.0.0.1:8001
```

Any idea what the difference could be? I've tried running it both daemonized and not.

This is the log when running with systemctl:

```
Proxy app started.
127.0.0.1:44391 [24/Dec/2014:09:01:42.403] main app/web1 0/0/-1/-1/0 503 212 - - SC-- 0/0/0/0/3 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

This is the log when running manually:

```
Proxy app started.
127.0.0.1:44393 [24/Dec/2014:09:02:11.758] main app/web1 0/0/0/2/2 200 5699 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

To be clear, I can successfully curl 127.0.0.1:8001 as both my deploy user, with sudo and the haproxy user.

## Edit with more info

I tried using nginx as a proxy instead, to no avail. So it is not haproxy that is at fault here. nginx says `502 Bad Gateway`, and the logs says:

```
2014/12/24 16:57:04 [crit] 23214#0: *1 connect() to 127.0.0.1:8001 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.34.1, server: www.zombieclj.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "www.zombieclj.local"
```

So yeah, there is some security thing going on. I am still able to curl to 127.0.0.1:8001. Stopping the firewall doesn't change anything.

Comment: When you start haproxy manually, what user account do you use?

Comment: What did haproxy log?

Comment: @JasonAzze I run it with sudo.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've only seen it log something along the lines of "Proxy app started", which isn't very useful.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've got some more logs now. The first is started from systemctl (503), the second is manually (200): https://gist.github.com/magnars/0dbf5d37f9c25b630f07

Answer (score 8):

The problem was SELinux only allowing the web server to make outbound connections to a limited set of ports.

Fixed by doing:

```
semanage port --add --type http_port_t --proto tcp 8001
```

after installing `semanage` with

```
yum install policycoreutils-python
```

[Nodejs Nginx error: (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream](https://serverfault.com/questions/634294/nodejs-nginx-error-13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstream)

Comment: This solution solved my problem. it should be marked as solution.

Comment: I ran into this issue when installing haproxy on a stock RHEL 7 image, for me the the port I wanted to use "8000" was already taken up by soundd_port_t so my solution involved some research using the Audit2Allow answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I used the Audit2Allow function found on the [centos wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-ad837f60830442ae77a81aedd10c20305a811388)

Review the rule:

`grep haproxy /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m haproxy`

Create a policy file (`*.pp`).

`grep haproxy /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M haproxy`

now when installing the package I also include the `haproxy.pp` file and load it to selinux with

`semodule -i haproxy.pp`

Comment: The port I was running the backend service on "8000" was already taken by something called soundd_port_t, I used the solution documented at https://www.mankier.com/8/haproxy_selinux#Booleans which is to allow haproxy to connect to any tcp port.