# haproxy fails to forward to backend server

Tags: haproxy

i'm trying to configure haproxy on a red hat 7.1 machine (haproxy 1.5.4)

to proxy a few nodejs instances.

if i try to access on port 80 (haproxy frontend) it returns error 503
if i try to access on port 3000 (node app service), it returns ok

here my haproxy configuration:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000
frontend  main *:80
    default_backend             app
backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    server  app1 127.0.0.1:3000 check
```

Any guidance is welcome.

Comment: What do your logs say? What about the stats page or socket; is the backend up? Also, if you're proxying on the same machine as the backend, why not just have Node listen on port 80, or use iptables to mangle the packets?

Comment: In your description you mention port 300 but in the config it points to port 3000.  This is a typo either in the post or your haproxy configs

Comment: @GregL, my backend answers ok, still no idea why it's not working. i've swapped my configuration with this one http://pastebin.com/y1ycT2kx but still not working. right now i've tested haproxy from command line instead service and it gave me this message:

$ haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg 
[WARNING] 312/175650 (533) : [haproxy.main()] Cannot raise FD limit to 8011.
[ALERT] 312/175650 (533) : Starting proxy http-in: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:80]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help, the problem was selinux. more details on this thread: [Weird interaction with systemctl with Haproxy on CentOS 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/654599/weird-interaction-with-systemctl-with-haproxy-on-centos-7)

all i needed to make was to run this command:

```
sudo semanage port --add --type http_port_t --proto tcp 3000
```

and changed my config file to this:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     1000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend  main 0.0.0.0:80
    default_backend             app

backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    server  app1 127.0.0.1:3000 check
```

Comment: Please mark your question as answered so other people don't come in to try help you out to find out you are good to go.

Comment: @DavidG serverfault/stackoverflow forbids me to do that in less than 48 hours. there's 17 hours left so i can do that.